# How do you execute a shell script from another shell using template_file?

Tags: terraform

I am using the TEMPLATE_FILE directive to execute a bootstrap bash script (call it "startup-script.sh") for a new GCP Compute Engine instance.  I've created a data template_file entry (see below) containing my script.  However, from inside my "startup-script.sh" script I want to execute another script containing functions and environment variables.  In other words, something like ". ../some-directory/some-script.sh" so that those functions and variables are available to my startup-script.sh script.  I'm not clear on how to do this.  If I try to execute "some-script.sh" from inside my startup-script.sh script, it can't be found.  Any advice is appreciated.

```
data "template_file" "startup-script" {
  template = "${file("startup-script.sh")}"

  vars {....
```

The "startup-script.sh" is just a bash script and the call that fails when "terraform apply" is issued looks simply like:

```
#!/bin/bash

. ../other_dir/other_script.sh
```

Comment: What does startup-script.sh and your other script look like? Have you tried sourcing it? I can't see why that wouldn't work but maybe I'm misunderstanding what you're trying to do.

Comment: It's just a bash shell script. If you reference a sources shell script in another directory then when you apply the template, it can't find the script.  The apply will fail.

Answer (score 0):

I'd create 2 data source `template_file`s, one for `other_script.sh` and one for the main `startup-script.sh`, and then combine them.

```hcl
data "template_file" "startup-script" {
  template = "${file("startup-script.sh")}"
}

data "template_file" "other_script" {
  template = "${file("other_script.sh")}"
}

resource "aws_instance" "app" {
  user_data = <<EOF
${data.template_file.other_script.rendered}
${data.template_file.startup-script.rendered}
EOF
}
```